# Canvas: Mouse Events

Tags: html, events, canvas, mouse

I know it is not possible to add eventhandlers to specific circles or rectangles in canvas. But there are some nice frameworks like EaselJS, KineticJS, Paper.js, Fabric.js that support the eventhandling on specific elements. 
Can someone explain me how do they work? 
I think there are only two solutions.
1. You create for each element a new canvas region and put them on each other. In this way you can give each region an event handler.
2. You have only one canvas region and one event handler. In this way you have to do complex mathematical calculations to find out if a specific element was clicked. If you have only circles or rectangles, this solution might be easy. But if you have path with lots of curves, this solution is quite difficult.

I don't want to use the libraries. So it would be nice, if someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

**Here's a BRIEF summary of how canvas drawing libraries work**

An unaltered canvas is just a big bitmap.  Once you draw shapes on the canvas, they are unaccessible, forgotten pixels.

Canvas drawing libraries store all your shapes into “retained” objects.  Each shape object has sufficient information about itself to allow the drawing library to redraw it whenever necessary.

The canvas drawing libraries are the "controllers" for objects. The libraries have the algorithms necessary to track, manipulate and redraw all shape objects as necessary.

The following information is retained about every shape object:

Basic identification

- ID,
- Shape name
- Parent or Container

Inherent  properties of the shape:

- Rectangular shapes( rect, image, text) know width and height.
- Circular shapes (circles, elipses, regular polygons, stars) know radius and sidecount.
- Lines know length.
- Curved shapes (arcs, beziers, paths) know anchor points and control points.
- Text also knows…well, the text!
- Images also know their pixel data (usually stored in javascript Image objects)

Transformational information:

- Starting X/Y coordinate
- Translations—accumulated movements off the starting coordinate.
- Rotations—accumulated rotations of this shape (usually in radians).
- Scalings—accumulated resizings
- Other transforms (less common) are skews and warps
- Layering information—the current z-index

Styling information:

- StrokeColor,
- StrokeWidth,
- FillColor,
- Opacity,
- isVisible,
- lineCaps,
- cornerRadius

Tracking abilities:

- Bounding box—the smallest rectangle that completely contains this shape
- This is used for “hit testing” to see if the mouse is inside this object (for selecting and dragging)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a library, you may find my answer [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343193/creating-speech-bubbles/14359738#14359738) helpful. As markE says once the canvas is written to there is no way of tracking that data (unless you care to loop through each individual pixel and test its colour; though that is only really useful for pixel level collision detection).